# Node, Mongoose: on save() "VersionError: No matching document found."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose so this is probably something *very* simple .. however.

I have a very simple schema that contains a simple array of numbers:

```
userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name        : String,
tag_id      : String,
badges      : [Number]
});

var user = mongoose.model( 'User', userSchema );
```

Later I want to add a badge to the user. So..

```
user.findOne({tag_id:tagid}, function(err,doc) {
     if (!doc) callback(false, 'no doc');

     // check to see if badge is in array, if not add it
     if ( doc.badges.indexOf(badgeNum) == -1 ) {
         doc.badges.push(badgeNum);
         doc.save( function(err) {
             if (err) callback( false, err );
             else callback( true, '');
         });
     } else {
         callback( false, 'user already had badge' )
     }
 });
```

However whenever I run that code I get a 'VersionError: No matching document found.'

I did a little googling and found reference to versioning being added in 3.x mongoose and that it's generally all handled internally. It should be noted that I loaded this user data straight into mongo via json and the mongo commandline ( so it wouldn't have the versioning variable defined by default, but I suspect that mongoose would create it if it didn't find it... bad assumption?)

EDIT: Sorry my simplified example had an error in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding versioning fields to my imported dataset and modifying the schema to associate it with versionKey.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

I do wonder, however if there isn't a setting that lets mongoose add the default versionkey (__v) to data that lacks it.

Comment: You might want to read [Aaron's blog post](http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.com/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html) about how the versionKey works.  If you're saving a regular Object into the DB, mongoose should add the versioning key behind the scenes.

Comment: I think, if I remember properly this was all caused because I sideloaded the data.

Comment: Hi, how did you add versioning fields to your data set and modify the schema to associate it with versionKey? Can you be a bit more specific? If so that would be great! Thanks! I'm having the exact same issue as you...

Comment: So I had an existing mongoose collection, none of the objects were created with mongoose. I simply went in (and I'm sorry I don't have the script around anymore) and added __v:0 to all the records as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the `testSchema` to the `user` object instead of the `userSchema` so it is looking for an document type that hasn't been created.

Update the user assignment to the following:

```
var user = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I would suggest you follow [the guides](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) if you aren't sure what you're doing.